# jQuery UI Droppable: Detect which draggables are dropped on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the jQuery UI framework's draggable and droppable elements working. I would like to programmatically determine which draggable elements are currently dropped on which droppable elements. Is there an easy way to do this?

I thought of using event listeners to detect `drop` and `out` events, then keep a dictionary or something in memory to keep track, but this seems contrived.

Better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class unique to the droppable to the elements when they are dropped in each droppable, then use selectors to get the elements that are in their respective droppable zone. You would have to be sure to remove the class as they are removed that that droppable though.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have Groups where you can drop Items on. 
The groups have a class `droppable` and the Items have a class `draggable`.

```
$('.droppable').each(function() {
    var currentGroupId = $(this).attr('id') //
    $(this).find('.draggable').each(function() {
        //get id of dropped item in current group 
        var droppedItemId = $(this).attr('id');         
    }
}
```

You can save the Id of the groups with the id´s of dropped items in that group to a field or dictionary or wherever you want.

This also works when you dynamicly add new items or groups.

Answer (score 0):

This is Explained on the documentation web Site but here it is again :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#catalog" ).accordion();
    $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Products

#### T-Shirts

- Lolcat Shirt
- Cheezeburger Shirt
- Buckit Shirt

#### Bags

- Zebra Striped
- Black Leather
- Alligator Leather

#### Gadgets

- iPhone
- iPod
- iPad

Shopping Cart

**ui.draggable.ATTRIBUTE (like text() attr() or others) is all what you need :)**